# Angular 11 Post Request Return SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: json, angular, http-post

I build an Angular app and when I try to make a POST request to my server(REST API with PHP) I get this error, but When I send request from Postman, everything is OK and I can see the result and absolutely its a valid JSON. note that all GET requests works properly.

in my component:

```
checkUser($username,$password)
  {
    this.webservice.Check_User($username,$password).subscribe((response) => {
      this.results=response;
    },(error) => { 
      console.error('Request failed with error:'+error)
    }
    );
   
  }
```

in my service:

```
Check_User($username,$password):Observable<any>
  {
    console.log('Request is sent!');
    let body = new HttpParams()
    .set('checkUser','checkUser')
    .set('username', $username)
    .set('password', $password);
    return this.http.post(this.Base_URL,
      body.toString(),{
        headers: new HttpHeaders()
          .set('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
          .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
          .set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',' true')
          .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','*')
          .set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','*')
      }).pipe( map(results => results)
      ,
        catchError((err) => {
          console.log('error caught in service')
          console.error(err); 
          return throwError(err);    //Rethrow it back to component
        })
    )
  }
```

I also tested various types of 'Content-Type' and 'responseType' in header, but still got error.

http response(body and header):

```
[{"fldUsername":"user","fldPassword":"password","fldName":"fldname","fldLname":"fldLname","fldCreatedate":"2021-01-04","fldCreatedtime":"19:17:29"}]
```

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length:181
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:*
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
X-Powered-By:PHP/7.3.12
Server:Apache/2.4.41 (Win64) PHP/7.3.12
```

thanks for any help

Comment: can you show the full http response (with body and headers) ?

Comment: @michael-desigaud i edited my question

Comment: the `Content-Type` header is set to `text/html` instead of `application/json`

Comment: i can get result with GET Requests and as explained before,i tested various content-types in php header and request header,but still have error

Comment: maybe GEt requests have valid http headers

Comment: i solved my problem by getting parameters with `file_get_contents("php://input")` in api(php) and send request's body as **raw** in angular with `application/json` content type in header. but still confused why `$_POST` dont work!